# Удаление строки из памяти

Tags: javascript, память

1. Есть страница, содержимое которой обновляется по AJAX.
2. При каждом обновлении по AJAX, на страницу приходит очень большая строка с Javascript-кодом.
3. Затем этот код выполняется через [`eval()`](https://learn.javascript.ru/eval) (проект достаточно старый, так что там реализовано именно так, плюс все переменные объявляются только через `var`).

[image: Отладочная панель]

При каждом обновлении страницы по AJAX в память добавляется новая строка (та, которая выполняется через `eval()`). Таким образом, каждое обновление страницы отъедает около 800 КБ оперативной памяти, т.е. возникает утечка памяти.

Почему так происходит, установить пока не удаётся. Возможно, что при выполнении JS-кода через `eval()`, строка остаётся в оперативной памяти. Как видно на скриншоте, **Distance** у таких строк равен нулю, значит, такие строки находятся на корневом уровне и какие-либо объекты на них не ссылаются.

Возможно ли каким-то образом выявить, почему эти строки остаются в оперативной памяти, раз на них никто не ссылаются? И можно ли их удалить из оперативной памяти без обновления страницы стандартным способом? Я буду признателен совершенно любой информации, которая поможет в решении этого вопроса.

Comment: Без кода помочь наверное никто не сможет(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогло решение с очисткой строк. Вот статья на Хабре: "[Нужно ли чистить строки в JavaScript?](https://habr.com/ru/post/449368/)".

Конкретно в моём случае подошёл следующий вариант:

```
//Очищаем строку после substr(), чтобы она не хранила ссылку на родителя
str = str.split('').join('');
```

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]